Where is the MAF sensor on a 2004 Subaru Forester XS?
I pulled a P0171 OBD-II diagnostic code (bank 1 fuel trim too lean) after getting a check engine light a couple weeks ago. The information I found tells me that the most likely solution is to clean or replace the MAF sensor in my car near the throttle body. I've scoured the internet looking for the location of this MAF sensor, along with checking under the hood to no avail. One Subaru forum post even claims that the 2003-2005 Forester line does not have a MAF sensor; instead it uses an MAP sensor.
So where is the MAF sensor? Do I even have one? Should I be looking into another potential cause for my check engine light?

Visit a Subaru Forester forum as they may have better info; https://www.subaruforester.org/threads/2004-p0171-system-too-lean-bank-1.696618/. 
